# Laravel URL::route and index.php

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel PHP framework for my website. In my navigation I have the `li` elements like these.

```
<li class="{{ URL::current() == URL::route("mainpage") ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="{{ URL::route("mainpage") }}">Home</a></li>
<li class="{{ URL::current() == URL::route("portfolio") ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="{{ URL::route("portfolio") }}">Portfolio</a></li>
```

I use `URL::route` to get links to named routes in my routes.php and use the `current` method to check if the page is active or not and add an `active` class to the element in that case.

This all works perfectly if the user doesn't have index.php in the path. If that is in the URL, then the links will look like `domain.com/index.php/portfolio` which is not good.

How do I make the links not to include index.php?

Comment: What version of Laravel you are using in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make sure the user always enters the website without the index.php in the URL. This can be done with a permament redirect, so you would need to modify your .htaccess and add a permament redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm using IIS so this doesn't work. Can't I just make the link be generated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check your /app/config/app.php file. If it contains

```
'index' => 'index.php'
```

remove the index.php (leave the value blank). Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for answering. My config file doesn't have that entry.

Comment: That option is in the lower versions of laravel 4